# Automatically updating variables with lambda

Tags: c#, variables, lambda, updates

I had a problem and I've asked around this community to assist me in solving the issue. The issue is to automatically update all the variables when a variable has been modified.

I've got tips to use [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58538701/12217837) to automatically update the variable `b`.

After this, I read a post stating about using get & set. However, even when I do something like this below, variable `b` wouldn't update.

```
private static int b;
        public int B
        {
            get { return b; }
            set { b = a + 5; }
        }
```

I couldn't also find a way to use lambda and get set together. Below is the code I use for testing.

```
class Class3
{
public class Storage
    {
        public static int a = 100;
        //public static int b => a + 5;
        public static int b => a + 5;
        public static int c;
    }
public static void Main()
    {
        Methods Test = new Methods();
        Console.WriteLine("Original a value: {0}", Storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", Storage.c);
        Test.Met1();
        Console.WriteLine("After met1: {0}", Storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", Storage.c);
        Test.Met2();
        Console.WriteLine("After met2: {0}", Storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", Storage.c);
        Test.Met3();
        Console.WriteLine("After met3: {0}", Storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", Storage.c);

        Storage.b += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);

    }
    public class Methods
    {
        public void Met1()
        {
            Storage.a -= 10;
            Storage.c = Storage.a;
        }
        public void Met2()
        {
            Storage.a -= 10;
            Storage.c = Storage.a;
        }
        public void Met3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Storage.a);
            Storage.c = Storage.a;
            Met1();
            Met2();
            if (Storage.a > 10)
            {
                Met3();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to see is `b` updating every time `a` changes value. In addition, the code shall allow the  `Storage.b += 1;` to update the value of b.

Is there a way to work around this? I really need help with this. If there is a link I could read, please share it with me. Thank you!

Comment: Don't make them static... they are *maintaining state*.

Comment: private int b = 0;
 private int a;
 public int A
        {
            get { return a; }
            set { a = value; b++; }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit - This works for both directly updating the value of B and also updating it when the value of A changes.*

I modified the `Storage` and `Methods` classes

```
        public class Storage
        {
            private int _a;

            public int A
            {
                get { return _a; }
                set
                {
                    _a = value;
                    B = value + 5;
                }
            }
            public int B { get; set; }
            public int C { get; set; }

            public Storage()
            {
                A = 100;
            }
        }

       public class Methods
        {
            private Storage _storage;

            public Methods(Storage storage)
            {
                _storage = storage;
            }
            public void Met1()
            {
                _storage.A -= 10;
                _storage.C = _storage.A;
            }
            public void Met2()
            {
                _storage.A -= 10;
                _storage.C = _storage.A;
            }
            public void Met3()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", _storage.A);
                _storage.C = _storage.A;
                Met1();
                Met2();
                if (_storage.A > 10)
                {
                    Met3();
                }
            }
        }
```

Inside `Main`

```
            var storage = new Storage();
            Methods Test = new Methods(storage);
            Console.WriteLine("Original a value: {0}", storage.A);
            Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.B);
            Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", storage.C);
            Test.Met1();
            Console.WriteLine("After met1: {0}", storage.A);
            Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.B);
            Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", storage.C);
            Test.Met2();
            Console.WriteLine("After met2: {0}", storage.A);
            Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.B);
            Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", storage.C);
            Test.Met3();
            Console.WriteLine("After met3: {0}", storage.A);
            Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.B);
            Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", storage.C);

            storage.B += 1;
            Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.B);
```

[image: Output from the program]

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, I will need to assign the formula to every get set property that it has relevance with.

Comment: @Nate - Not sure if I follow, but if you wish to use formulas, then use an explicit property, otherwise use an auto property. I guess you are saying the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could work for you. You'll just need to use properties and hide the member variables.

Of course, as mentioned, I would also suggest that you don't use static variables and getters.

```
public static class Storage
{
    private static int a = 100;
    public static int A {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; b = a + 5; }
    }

    private static int b = a + 5;
    public static int B {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }
    public static int c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you  Athanasios Kataras, I will need to assign the formula to every get set property that it has relevance with.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how the class should be:

```
public class Storage
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b => a + 5;
    public int c { get; set; }

    public void Met1()
    {
        this.a -= 10;
        this.c = this.a;
    }

    public void Met2()
    {
        this.a -= 10;
        this.c = this.a;
    }

    public void Met3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", this.a);
        this.c = this.a;
        Met1();
        Met2();
        if (this.a > 10)
        {
            Met3();
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is how you can use it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Storage storage = new Storage();
        storage.a = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("Original a value: {0}", storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", storage.c);
        storage.Met1();
        Console.WriteLine("After met1: {0}", storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", storage.c);
        storage.Met2();
        Console.WriteLine("After met2: {0}", storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", storage.c);
        storage.Met3();
        Console.WriteLine("After met3: {0}", storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", storage.c);

        Console.ReadKey();
        //storage.b += 1;
        //Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", storage.b);
    }
```

Please note that if b is equal to a + 5, you cannot assign a value to b.

Comment: Thank you CyberZeus, but there is a tedious way and its to assign the formula in every other get set property that the formula is involved in.